# EasyPHP connecting to MS Access

Tags: ms-access, windows-xp, easyphp

I want to know if I can connect easyphp to an MS Access database to store data into it?

Can anybody point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest connecting to an ODBC datasource from php.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this step by step article on how to setup an ODBC connection, and connecting to the Access database using that ODBC connection.

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_db_odbc.asp